# Can I manually trigger before insert function for already inserted records in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers

I am using PostgreSQL 14.5

I have a `beneficiaries` table where people are registered and I have `BEFORE INSERT` trigger function that generates a unique `ID` based on their location (if Paris - PAR-001, if London - LON-004, etc) and it works.

But the problem is, lots of records are inserted before writing this function, and since the function is triggered `BEFORE INSERT` I can't have the `ID`s for them.

I have seen the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) and didn't find how to trigger the function for previous records

Can I manually trigger this function for all records once or any other solution?

Comment: Re-insert and then delete old records. Roughly speaking something like `insert into the_table select * from the_table where id is null; delete from the_table where id is null;`

Comment: The table has hard relations with other tables too not to just re-insert them. Your solution would have worked if not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an additional trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER temp BEFORE UPDATE ON tab
   FOR EACH ROW WHEN (OLD.id IS NULL)
   EXECUTE FUNCTION your_trigger_func();
```

The trigger function is the one you use in your `BEFORE INSERT` trigger. Then update all these rows:

```
UPDATE tab SET id = id WHERE id IS NULL;
```

You can drop the trigger when you are done.

You can perform the update in batches and run `VACUUM` on the table in between, to avoid bloat by a single massive update.